# Use arrayformula to count columns in rows

Tags: google-sheets

I want to count the number of columns containing entries in them per row.

I used the formula :

```
=ArrayFormula(countif($H$4:$4,"<"&$A$4:$A)/count($H$4:$4))
```

Comment: Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Answer (score 1):

this might work...

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A4:A="",,MMULT(N(OFFSET(H4,,,ROWS(H4:H),COLUMNS(H4:4))<>""),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(H4:4),1,1,0))))
```